# a martingale equality

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X_{t}$ a  positive  continuous martingale satisfying:
 $\lim_{t\longrightarrow \infty}X_{t}=0 $ ps and $X_{0}=a \in {R_{+}}$
Show that $\textbf{P}(\sup_{t\geq0}X_{t} \geq b)=\frac{a}{b}$ , a < b

Does anybody know how to prove this? Some help would be appreciated

Comment: i already prove that  $\textbf{P}(\sup_{t\geq0}X_{t} \geq b) \leq \frac{a}{b}$ (according to the submartingale inequality) but i can't prove the other inequality.Some help would be appreciated

Comment: Obviously this cannot hold for every (a,b). Assume that X is integer valued then the LHS is the same for a=1 and b=2.2 or b=2.3, but not the RHS. What is your source?

Comment: And now the hypothesis that X is path continuous appeared in the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $Y = \sup_{t\ge0} X_t$. We'll prove $P(Y> b)=a/b$ for $0\le a < b$. If we can prove this, it will follow by a continuity argument that $P(Y\ge b)=a/b$ as well.

To do this, we first rewrite the probability in terms of a stopping time. Define
$$
  T = \inf\{t\ge0\mid X_t >b\}.
$$
The variable $T$ is a stopping time. If $T<\infty$, then there is $t\ge0$ such that $X_t > b$, yielding $Y>b$. Conversely, if $Y>b$, there exists $t\ge0$ such that $X_t>b$, so $T<\infty$. We therefore conclude that $(Y> b)=(T<\infty)$, and so it suffices to prove $P(T<\infty) = a / b$.

Now, as $a<b$, we always have $T>0$, since $X$ has initial value $a$ and has continuous sample paths. Therefore, by continuity, we have $X_T = b$ whenever $T$ is finite. As $X$ is nonnegative and continuous, we conclude that the stopped process $X^T$ is bounded by $b$. Therefore, $X^T$ is a uniformly integrable martingale, so $EX^T_\infty = EX_0 = a$. However, by assumption, $X_\infty$ is almost surely zero. Therefore, we obtain
$$
  X^T_\infty = X_\infty1_{(T=\infty)} + X_T1_{(T<\infty)} = b 1_{(T<\infty)},
$$
and thus, recalling our earlier conclusions, we find
$$
  a = EX^T_\infty = E b 1_{(T<\infty)} = bP(T<\infty) = b P(Y > b),
$$
which yields the result to be proven.

Comment: "since X has initial value a and has continuous sample paths" I see no hypothesis that the paths of X are continuous.

Comment: Oh, good point, I must've misread the question. I also wondered why you mentioned the stuff about being integer-valued in your comment if $X$ had continuous sample paths... Guess it all makes sense now :-)

Comment: sorry, i made a mistake : the martingale had continuous sample paths. what argument of continuity did you use?

Comment: Why $X_{T}=b$ and not $X_{T}>b$ ?

Comment: That $X_T = b$ is one point where the continuity of the sample paths is used. Now, $X$ starts in $a$ and $a<b$, and $T$ is the first time where $X$ increases beyond $b$. Therefore, $X_t<b$ for all $t<T$. By continuity, then, $X_T \le b$. Furthermore, $X_T\ge b$ by a standard infimum-type argument. So $X_T = b$. Intuitively, the lack of jumps means that the first time $X$ is beyond $b$ is where $X$ hits $b$.

Comment: ok, i understand now